# Gnuplot plots graph of equation wrong?

Tags: gnuplot, equation

When plotting the equation below, I get a wrong graph. Wolfram alpha and my calculator see the crossing point through f(x)=0 at x=112.77. Gnuplot shows it at approximately 115.8 ~ 116

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

#Ranges
set xrange [112:116]
set yrange [-0.5:0.5]
set samples 10000

#Special drawings
f(x) =   (101300-1.225/2*x**2) *0.0167*x /((288.15-1/(2*1005)*x**2)*287)-2.1774


plot f(x) title "f(v)" with lines ls 1

pause -1
```

Can someone reproduce this problem and help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition

```
f(x) =   (101300-1.225/2*x**2) *0.0167*x /((288.15-1/(2*1005)*x**2)*287)-2.1774
```

includes the term `1/(2*1005)`. All the numbers in this expression are integers, so gnuplot uses integer arithmetic, in which 1/2010 = 0. You have to convert at least one of those numbers to a floating point number so that you get the expected behavior, for example

```
f(x) =   (101300-1.225/2*x**2) *0.0167*x /((288.15-1./(2*1005)*x**2)*287)-2.1774
```

Note that I replaced `1` by `1.`, which tells gnuplot that this is to be treated as a floating point number. In general, it is often better to write all constants as floats unless you are absolutely sure that you want integer arithmetic.